# How to solve this employer schedule problem, functionally?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, linear-programming

My intention with this question is to acquire a start point to work and solve this problem. I do not intend to have a complete answer that solves magically my problem.

*Context*

A company have 66 employers. However, because of COVID pandemic they only have 41 office chairs (aka places) per day. By days I mean only a week (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri)

To solve this, they created three categories of workers:

1. Those who will have a fixed place, do not having home office (10)
2. Those who will have only 1 day of home office (7)
3. Those who will have 2 days of home office (49)

I need to combine all workers with all chair such way that all 41 chairs will be filled.

There're some constraints (there're more, but for sake of simplicity I'll say only 2):

1. Workers cannot be at home office on consecutive days
2. Workers cannot choose to be on home office on Friday and then Monday. (Example: Worker 1 has 2 home office days, then he chooses Friday and then Monday, so he will be at home for 4 days)

*What I made*

Ok, so I started to think how can I solve this, however I'm stuck...

What I made for now is the data model and some helpers functions, however I'm having difficult to think on a real solution. How can I start? Is not a simple combination problem and is my first of this type.

This is my data model:

```hs
data Day = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri deriving (Show)

data Category = Fixed | OneDay | TwoDays deriving (Show)

data Function = Director | Manager | Common deriving (Show)

data Worker = W { name       :: String
                , occupation :: String
                , category   :: Category
                , group      :: String
                , squad      :: String
                , function   :: Function
                } deriving (Show)

data Schedule = S [(Worker, [Day])] deriving (Show)

type Workers = [Worker]

-- | Helpers

numWorkers :: Int
numWorkers = 66

numChairs :: Int
numChairs = 41

days :: [Int]
days = [1..5]

haveNoDays :: Worker -> Bool
haveNoDays W{category=Fixed} = True
haveNoDays _                 = False

haveOneDay :: Worker -> Bool
haveOneDay W{category=OneDay} = True
haveOneDay _                  = False

haveTwoDays :: Worker -> Bool
haveTwoDays W{category=TwoDays} = True
haveTwoDays _                   = False

decreaseCategory :: Worker -> Worker
decreaseCategory w@W{category=c} =
  case c of
    Fixed   -> w
    OneDay  -> w {category = Fixed}
    TwoDays -> w {category = OneDay}

-- | Main functions

schedule :: Workers -> Schedule
schedule _ = S []
```

Comment: You can try the brute force approach: generate all possible solutions, then filter out those that don't meet your constraints.

Comment: Yeah, someone already said that to me, however it already exist a spreadsheet that they manually updates. I need to implement an automatic way to combine these data. My doubt is: How can I do a brute force in the code?

Comment: How long do you expect the lists of days in your `Schedule` to be, infinite?

Comment: No! This `Schedule` have a list of tuples, each tuple has a `Worker` and all days that this `Worker` will be in the office. I thought that makes sense, but I can also change this model.

Comment: The model is probably fine, but you still didn't answer my question: how many days do the lists in the tuples include? How many weeks does your `Schedule` encompass? Or another way to put it: are there any constraints on the *first* day of the schedule? And how does `schedule` know on which day to start the scheduling?

Comment: Oh, okay, Now I get your question! `Schedule` starts on Monday and needs to run infinitely. I imagined this situation: "we need a schedule for N weeks, here are all employers (xs)", so the function would return a `Schedule` starting on Monday and then cycles through N weeks combining between Monday and Friday. Does it answers you?

Comment: For brute forcing, you then need a function `schedules :: Int -> Workers -> [Schedule]` that generates all imaginable schedules of N weeks, starting with those where nobody is at the office any day at all to those where everybody comes in every day. Then `schedule = head . filter isValidSchedule . schedule 2`

Comment: Highly recommend looking at a CP solver (constraint programming) like IBM CPLEX. It's built for this sort of thing.

Comment: Google OR Tools is also a good bet.

Comment: I'm with @MLavrentyev. Don't bother with Haskell. Go straight to a SAT solver or similar; z3 or yices would both chew through this instantly. If you'd like a Haskell-like language to write the SAT query in, have a look at [cryptol](https://cryptol.net/) -- the way that would work is you'd write down a functional program that, when given an assignment of people to chairs, checks if that assignment is valid (meets all the constraints you listed). Then a `:sat` in the cryptol repl will ask a solver for an assignment that meets the constraints.

Comment: The question reminds me of [my favorite tutorial - how to plan a picnic with haskell](http://www.lisperati.com/haskell/)

Comment: I'd partially agree with @DanielWagner, but only partially. Yes, I'd also use a SMT solver, but via great `sbv` Haskell library. I really enjoy using for solving problems like this.

Comment: Doing some basic math here says something is wrong.  Drop the 10 people who are always there and remove 10 chairs.  We have 31 chairs left, or 155 chair-days per week.  If we don't look at constraints, you have 7*4 = 28 chair days plus 49*3 = 147 chair days = 175 chair days needed.  I don't think that's solvable.  If it's really "I have 41 chairs for the rotating people", then you have 205 chair days available.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @arrowd do you have any example project that uses `sbv` on a more complex problem that ones from docs?

Comment: @DanielWagner How I could use a cryptography language for solving combinatory problem? There's any example? I don't need to bother with Haskell haha. I want to use the right tool for the right problem. Only chosen Haskell because is what I know more

Comment: @Mdsp The [examples/funstuff](https://github.com/GaloisInc/cryptol/tree/master/examples/funstuff) directory in the repo has several examples of using cryptol for solving logic problems similar to the one you describe.

Comment: @Mdsp Not in public, but I used `sbv` to find solutions for a system of differential equations. I'd say this is a pretty complex project. `sbv` is basically an EDSL for querying SMT solvers directly from Haskell, so it is almost as powerful as Z3 itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for a starting point and not a solution, I'll walk through a brute force way that you could use to think about solving this functionally, but which **is not** computationally practical.

Emphasis again: **this is not a practical solution, and even as brute force solutions go, you can probably do better**

I'm also going to try to solve for the 1 week version of this, with the assumption that the 1 week schedule will repeat indefinitely.  Note that this assumption doesn't necessarily have to be true (it's possible that there's a solution that would require 2 weeks in order to allocate).  If we accept that assumption, one of your constraints will say that people who have 2 days off can't have both Monday and Friday off.

I'll use a really simplified version of your data model.

```
data Location = Home | Office deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Let's ignore the workers that are always in the office.  They always consume the same number of chairs every day.  In practical terms, if you have 41 chairs, and 10 employees that are there every day, you have 31 chairs left for your employees that have flexible schedules.

For your employees who are home once a week, their weekly schedule will be one of the  permutations of

```
[Home, Office, Office, Office, Office]
```

and your employees who are at home twice a week will be one of the permutations of

```
[Home, Home, Office, Office, Office]
```

but you'll exclude the `[Home,Office,Office,Office,Home]` since that would violate your constraint.

Let's name some types and grossly abuse lists to make things simple:

```
type WorkerSchedule = [Location]   -- a schedule for an individual worker
type PossibleSchedule = [WorkerSchedule]  -- a list of possible schedules for a worker
type FullSchedule = [WorkerSchedule] -- represents a list of workers with the schedule that they will work
type WorkerSchedules = [PossibleSchedule] -- represents the brute force pool of schedules
type ChairCount = Int
```

Here's a dumb, brute force algorithm:

1. For each of your workers, create a `PossibleSchedule` that represents all of the possible ways that worker can be scheduled in a given week.
2. Create a list of your workers' possible schedules (7 of one type, 49 of the other)
3. Create a list of chairs that you have available every day [31,31,31,31,31]
4. Start at the beginning of the worker list, with the first possible schedule for the first worker, with all of the chairs available.
5. Find a way to solve for the rest of the workers, but with one fewer chair on each of the days that the worker will be in the office.
   a. If there's a solution, then we just take our schedule and jam it onto the solution we found for the rest of the workers.
   b. If there's no solution, then try again using the next possible schedule for that first worker.  If there are no more possible schedules, then there is no solution.

You might end up with something that looks like:

```
findSchedule :: [ChairCount] -> WorkerSchedules -> Maybe Fullschedule
findSchedule chairs [] = Just []        --Nobody left to schedule!
findSchedule chairs ([]:xss) = Nothing  --No other schedules I can try for this worker
findSchedule chairs ((x:xs):xss) =
  case buildChairCountAfterWorker chairs x of
    Nothing -> findSchedule chairs (xs:xss) --Try next schedule
    Just newChairs -> case findSchedule newChairs xss of
                        Nothing -> findSchedule chairs (xs:xss) --Try next schedule 
                        Just sched -> Just (x:sched) --Return solution
```

In this case, `buildChairCountAfterWorker` is a helper function that takes a list of chairs, a proposed schedule for the worker, and returns a `Maybe [ChairList]` which will be nothing if there are not sufficient chairs on one of the days, or otherwise provides the number of chairs remaining for everyone else.

So....this is functional and "correct", but not practical.  Let's assume that your employees are fixed (you have the 56 employees as described in the problem).

```
*Constraints> findSchedule [5,5,5,5,5] allEmployees
Nothing
(0.07 secs, 43,830,416 bytes)
```

Ok - that's reasonable.  We clearly can't fit all those people into 5 chairs.

```
*Constraints> findSchedule [51,51,51,51,51] allEmployees
Just <schedule removed for clarity>
(0.13 secs, 35,608,720 bytes)
```

Awesome. When we have a lot of room to find a solution, we don't have to explore the solution space very far.

```
*Constraints> findSchedule [6,6,6,6,6] allEmployees 
Nothing
(0.49 secs, 373,728,960 bytes)
*Constraints> findSchedule [7,7,7,7,7] allEmployees 
Nothing
(13.56 secs, 9,336,407,864 bytes)
*Constraints> findSchedule [8,8,8,8,8] allEmployees 
Nothing
(328.77 secs, 250,233,745,768 bytes)
```

Uh - that doesn't look good.  If we constrain ourselves to 8 chairs, it still takes 5 minutes to get far enough down the solution space to confirm that we don't have a solution.

Closing in on more constrained solution from the top isn't any better:

```
*Constraints> findSchedule [47,47,47,47,47] allEmployees
(149.57 secs, 112,385,139,968 bytes)
```

You can almost certainly do better than this algorithm, but the takeaway is probably that you should be using a specialized solver as discussed in the comments to your original post.  Dumb brute force is always going to run into an exponential problem that looks a lot like 9**(number of employees).